# iAd Testads only showing on iPhone4's never on iPads and iPhone3GS

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, iad, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a problem with the iAds library regarding Betatest.

First of. I use Monotouch, and the App is build for the iPhone. 
All tests has been done on devices that run iOS6.

The devices are iPad2,3, iPhone3GS and 2xiPhone4

The Problem is that the AdBannerView test ad only shows up on the 2 iPhone4's. 
But also works in both iPhone Emulators (Retina and Non-retina)

So iPads, and Iphone3GS shows no ads.

Since this is not an iPad App, there could be some logic in the Ad's not working on the iPad. Even though I would say that would be weird because you can install iPhone app's on the iPad.

But more weird is the fact that it does not work on iPhone3GS.

I can post some code, but it is my feeling that the problem has to do with setup. I.e. a lot of places I have seen that I have to enable iAds in my App using iTunes Connect.
But as far as I can see this is only when I release the App.

Does anybody have a clues as to why this can happen ?

Will it only happen with TestAds ?

BTW: This guy has a similiar problem even though he does not mention whether he talks about TestAds [iAD Working only on Some Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700796/iad-working-only-on-some-devices)
But his question is unanswered.

BTW2: I live in a country that does not support iAds. But As far as I know this should not be a problem regarding TestAds.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that all your device enabled for development.

Next compare your device settings between the one that *works* and the ones that do **not** works. You'll find this in:

**Settings > Developer > iAd Developer App Testing**

Comment: Thank you. There is a Settings -> Developer, but not a setting for iAD on one of the iPhone4 that works. The other devices are not enabled for development. They are betatesters - so they install via itunes - have sent me their device Ids. One of them have an iPhone4 and that one works. So I think it should be possible without me installing the Developer Provisioning profile on their device ?! Is it your experience that I have to do that ?

Comment: @JesperNiedermann Sorry I'm not sure what is the behaviour of the **test** ads outside development. Last time I checked I got empty ads (for my geographical location) but that was pre-6.0 and I recall some stuff, and settings, changed since then.

Comment: Today I tried to make one of the iPads into a developer device. But no ads are served just as before. Even if I set fill rate to 100%. Hmm. I am worried if this will also be a problem in production.